# Visual studio 2013 cannot resolve metadata. C# Store app

Tags: c#, sdk, visual-studio-2013

I installed an sdk to upload my app to the store. After the package creation I went home, only to see this error the next day when I started VS2013 again. *note: It worked fine the same day I installed it, problem began after system reboot*

error:

Cannot resolve 'Windows.metadata'.  Please install the Windows Software Development Kit. You can retarget your project to Windows 8.1. The Windows 8.1 SDK is installed with Visual Studio. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=278967&clcid=0x409 for more information on how to retarget your project

So I reinstalled the development kit and followed the steps on the Microsoft website, but i still can't retarget it (VS doesn't provide me with an option to do so), also, VS tells me my app already is targeted to 8.1.

Anyone has any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most stupid problem ever. Missed the visual update 2013 update. Just updated it and now its fine